# Set the transparency of (MarkerFace) data points in a scatter plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to set the transparency of (MarkerFace) data points in a scatter plot in Matlab. I can see this has been asked before and most answers suggest using using `patch`. This isn't working for me, can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

```
h(1) = scatter(x1,y1,30,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 0.5 0.5],'MarkerFaceColor', [0 0.5 0.5]);
hold on
h(2) = scatter(x2,y2,30,'MarkerEdgeColor','g','MarkerFaceColor', 'g');
h(3) = scatter(x3,y3,30,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 0.3906 0],'MarkerFaceColor', [0 0.3906 0]);
h(4) = scatter(x4,y4,30,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0.4961 1.0000 0.8281],'MarkerFaceColor', [0.4961 1.0000 0.8281]);

PatchInPlot = findobj(h([1 2 3 4]), 'type', 'patch');
set(PatchInPlot, 'facea', 0.5)
```

Comment: Because your example is not self contained (i.e. doesn't run by itself) it's difficult to get to know what you mean by "isn't working for me". Giving a better example and printing the error message or a description of doesn't work would help with the answer.

Comment: It is not that simple to make an self contained example. Use x1 = 1:5; y1 = 1:5 and remove all scatter plots except 1.

Answer (score 1):

The `FaceAlpha` property does not really refer to the markers. It rather refers to the area the markers span over, try

```
h = scatter(1:5,1:5,30,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0.4961 1.0000 0.8281],'MarkerFaceColor', [0.4961 1.0000 0.8281]);
PatchInPlot = findobj(h, 'type', 'patch');
set(PatchInPlot(2),'XData',[3.5;4.5;4.5;3.5;3.5],'YData',[3.5;3.5;4.5;4.5;3.5]);
set(PatchInPlot(2),'FaceColor',[1,0,0]);
set(PatchInPlot, 'facea', 0.2);
```

If you have a reasonable number of points that you want to plot you can consider creating a patch polygon for each marker and then set the transparity for each polygon. It may not be the only way, but I cannot give a better answer.

Comment: Thanks @patrik, this is useful however I have many points. One way is possibly to make a white transparent patch (alpha ~.2) covering the whole plot. X = [0;5;5;0;0];Y = [0;0;5;5;0];
P = patch(X,Y,'w');
set(P, 'facea', 0.2);